# How to decrease size of vendor.js in angular 2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

Angular CLI creates `vendor.js` and I don't know Why and What is the use of it?? Size of this file is about **3.2MB** for a new app!!

Does this file contains *Angular 6 Javascript Source*?

Don't you think this is big file for loading on internet on low speed connections?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This file includes all libraries that you added into your project. If you build your app on production mode the file size will be smaller.

```
ng build --prod
```

Comment: After using Prod also my project size is 8Mb which getting more time to load. May i know what to do ??

Comment: you mean files inside dist folder? you can check in that folder which file cause this.

Answer (score 36):

Try

```
ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer
```

I reduced my vender.**.js fromm 12mb to 2mb

Comment: In Angular 9 , I can't find the vendor-chunk anywhere after running  ng build --prod

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179853/angular-should-i-use-the-vendorchunk-in-production

Comment: Didn't change antyhing for me

Comment: Nice. 8mb to 880Kbs

Answer (score 9):

Instead of decreasing it you can remove the file completely
By specifying the `--build-optimizer` flag, the cli will disable this file from the build output.

The CLI will now bundle the vendor code into the main.js bundle, which will also enable uglification to reduce the size.

So you will see a small increase in the size of the main.js bundle which is minimal in comparison to the size of the vendor chunks

Comment: I didn't give any difference in our build

Comment: No difference for me and vendor remains

Comment: @Karthikeyan then check the version doc. Its automatically done in more recent versions of angular

Answer (score 6):

You may also want to update your build script in package.json to generate a prod build by default.  I ran into this deploying to Heroku, since it runs 'npm build' automatically.  By default, 'npm build' runs the following script:

```
ng build
```

If you update it to

```
ng build --prod
```

in package.json, then Heroku/AWS/Azure will create a production build on deployment instead.

Answer (score 5):

At the angular.json configuration file you need to change the values:

```
 "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "aot": true,
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using C# as backend with the default template, make sure to actually use the production configuration from your `angular.json`:

```
...
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build-prod" />
...
```

Since I switched to a newer angular version, `--prod` was no longer supported and I incorrectly assumed that `ng build` would default to production...
Furthermore I had to adapt the production configuration as described by @edyrkaj

You could change the `package.json` as well by adding all those options to the build command, but I prefer the angular.json approach since it's a lot nicer to read and maintain in my opinion