# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). vendor.js

Tags: angular, windows, asp.net-core, client-side, vendor-prefix

I am following a tutorial on building a web app with ASP.NET Core and Angular 12. After creating the first component I built the app I got the initial chunk files BUT minus the vendor.js. In the tutorial, the vendor.js file is actually among the chunk files and so I manually downloaded and added the vendor.js file. However, when I run the command 'ng build', the vendor.js file disappears from solution explorer. When I debug the app I get a blank page and the console message errors as shown in the image.

Later on, I read somewhere that vendor.js is used during production. Could this be the reason it disappears?[image] Please let me know if you need more info to solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say, you manually downloaded and added the `vendor.js` file. I actually don't know why you do that manually.`vendor.js` is a compiled file that angular generates for you. I will recommend you Update the node to the latest version and the Angular CLI version also upgrade the angular project version.

right now, I assume that your `vendor.js` is too high so that you found this issue. follow the below process:-

run this command:- `ng build --prod --vendor-chunk=true` or `ng build --prod`    [Angular Should I use the vendorChunk in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179853/angular-should-i-use-the-vendorchunk-in-production)  if not work then try below process:-

Maybe like to be an issue with caching. Run this command:-

`npm cache clean` or `npm cache verify` or `npm cache --force clean`  Also, Update the node to the latest version and Angular CLI version.

if not work, then follow the second process:-

Change index.html `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`

if not work, then follow third process:-

Add useHash:true in your route module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/your-route/
  ]

...................
```

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Pritom Sarkar. It really needed updating node to the most recent version and running build --prod.