# Is it advisable to split main.js bundle into main and vendor bundle for production build in angular by setting vendorChunk to true?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, web

I have http2 on production and currently my "vendorChunk" flag is false which is creating main.js bundle around 1.4 MB. Downloading such a huge file is taking around 1.5 second. If I split it into main and vendor so size will be reduced to 600-700kb for each bundle which will be downloaded in parallel as I'm using http2. Shouldn't that work? Any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Should I use the vendorChunk in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179853/angular-should-i-use-the-vendorchunk-in-production)

Comment: No, That's separate kind of question. Please read my use case for performance point of view.